# How to remove active class with click in my case

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick, modal-dialog

I wanted to make a gallery of Unsplash images and provide a full-screen image when the user will click on a small image. I make a modal window, which appears when the user clicking on the small image, and I wanted to close it when it clicks to any place in such a modal window. I make the anonymous function which must change my active to false, but when I clicked nothing happened.

Here is the code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jis6bz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js line 26 you should clean modalActive variable if you are clicking on an element which is already in modalActive

```
App.js line 26:
     onClick={() => (
        modalActive === index ? setModalActive(null) : setModalActive(index) 
     )}
```

And it will be more clean code approach if onClick will be a function with name, not an anonymous, something like *toggleActiveImage*